# Tor Error: bind: cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, tor, debian-buster

I config a tor bridge on Debian 10. it did work well but now it will show this:

```
Mar 04 22:09:50.603 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.8 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.603 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
    Mar 04 22:09:50.603 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 2889 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:8080
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opened OR listener on 0.0.0.0:8080
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opening Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:0
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Extended OR listener listening on port 38145.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.606 [notice] Opened Extended OR listener on 127.0.0.1:0
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Configured to measure statistics. Look for the *-stats files that will first be written to the data directory in 24 hours from now.
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Your Tor server's identity key fingerprint is 'MJBN FB1E7F6E2E0F0BE2CF3B864F68B449E0200225C0'
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Your Tor bridge's hashed identity key fingerprint is 'MJBN AD4BDB71232E6D5C3FC1CD111928E04B618F152F'
    Mar 04 22:09:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
    Mar 04 22:09:51.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
    Mar 04 22:09:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
    Mar 04 22:09:51.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
    Mar 04 22:09:51.000 [warn] Server managed proxy encountered a method error. (obfs4 listen tcp 134.209.88.233:29930: bind: cannot assign requested address)
    Mar 04 22:09:51.000 [warn] Managed proxy at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' failed the configuration protocol and will be destroyed.
    Mar 04 22:14:28.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:42. Giving up.
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 724E86E7F5DA715529DC0ECAA013AE4BDC680E4C at 5.9.29.183:9002)
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn] 10 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 9695DFC35FFEB861329B9F1AB04C46397020CE31 at 128.31.0.34:9101)
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn] 11 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:51.000 [warn]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:20:54.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host FA1845C313B88EF49E8BE1F23B02CD0AC702B636 at 95.216.14.206:443)
    Mar 04 22:20:54.000 [warn] 12 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:20:54.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:54.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:20:54.000 [warn]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:21:05.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host E6C04728E9339DF22F331B7017D4A7AA3F252F0B at 149.202.208.203:443)
    Mar 04 22:21:05.000 [warn] 13 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:21:05.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:05.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:05.000 [warn]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:21:06.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 7AAF5597B18D82CC90CA95FB7976A1CEA4A32E06 at 185.112.82.50:443)
    Mar 04 22:21:06.000 [warn] 14 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:21:06.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:06.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:06.000 [warn]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:21:08.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (IOERROR; IOERROR; count 15; recommendation warn; host F0015B65503361F30E540193969DDE64E411C801 at 64.227.6.176:443)
    Mar 04 22:21:08.000 [warn] 15 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:21:08.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:08.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:21:08.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 at 193.23.244.244:443)
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn] 16 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host F4A4D78F16E9A0353AD5BBEF4632C7022E20FB20 at 51.15.54.71:9001)
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn] 17 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:51.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:22:54.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 906A42DD880A2CBEDD52F3F28FE9F942A865F715 at 173.255.250.219:9001)
    Mar 04 22:22:54.000 [warn] 18 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:22:54.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:54.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:22:54.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:23:14.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host 3E53D3979DB07EFD736661C934A1DED14127B684 at 217.79.179.177:9001)
    Mar 04 22:23:14.000 [warn] 19 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:23:14.000 [warn]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:14.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:14.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:23:15.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host 9B2BC7EFD661072AFADC533BE8DCF1C19D8C2DCC at 188.127.69.60:443)
    Mar 04 22:23:15.000 [warn] 20 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:23:15.000 [warn]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:15.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:15.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:23:16.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 21; recommendation warn; host 1F4105C688E835A56AF3D66C787677B57240FFA2 at 149.202.190.14:9001)
    Mar 04 22:23:16.000 [warn] 21 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:23:16.000 [warn]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:16.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:23:16.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 22; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443)
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn] 22 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host 4FC2B318D8F0F740B46E694D08107948D7374809 at 185.108.129.144:443)
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn] 23 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:51.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:24:54.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host B817C6299E56517874F3019E51C27E5BE47E7284 at 176.67.169.254:443)
    Mar 04 22:24:54.000 [warn] 24 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:24:54.000 [warn]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:54.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:24:54.000 [warn]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:25:56.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (IOERROR; IOERROR; count 25; recommendation warn; host 04D892C23D4B26D55B2669A3A7E6C67C8817172B at 109.24.234.220:9001)
    Mar 04 22:25:56.000 [warn] 25 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:25:56.000 [warn]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:25:56.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:25:56.000 [warn]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:26:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 26; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at 131.188.40.189:443)
    Mar 04 22:26:51.000 [warn] 26 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:26:51.000 [warn]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:26:51.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:26:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:06.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 27; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at 171.25.193.9:80)
    Mar 04 22:28:06.000 [warn] 27 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:06.000 [warn]  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:06.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:06.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:22.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 28; recommendation warn; host 8A2CCF9A354EF89C08CB0AE2DD7F7E8418ADF713 at 139.178.49.166:9001)
    Mar 04 22:28:22.000 [warn] 28 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:22.000 [warn]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:22.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:22.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:23.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 29; recommendation warn; host 60820A2820446DD90E068ED3E121497C809F3D65 at 163.172.168.183:9001)
    Mar 04 22:28:23.000 [warn] 29 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:23.000 [warn]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:23.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:23.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:24.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 30; recommendation warn; host 74B41DED505CFABC7A8D439362FC9B6589DE4591 at 91.132.60.9:443)
    Mar 04 22:28:24.000 [warn] 30 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:24.000 [warn]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:24.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:24.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 31; recommendation warn; host 8E76F1F6E8499CCE975C451560586A5F8BF0BFDB at 185.86.150.58:9001)
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn] 31 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 32; recommendation warn; host 24E2F139121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at 204.13.164.118:443)
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn] 32 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:28:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:30:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 33; recommendation warn; host 1C7D71A2581DE79C5CFC4ED1FF75D5BE30F01BB7 at 51.15.243.22:443)
    Mar 04 22:30:51.000 [warn] 33 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:30:51.000 [warn]  18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:51.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:51.000 [warn]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:30:52.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (IOERROR; IOERROR; count 34; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 45.66.33.45:443)
    Mar 04 22:30:52.000 [warn] 34 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:30:52.000 [warn]  18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:52.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:52.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:30:55.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 35; recommendation warn; host 956C4D93C8D8A6890B52BF76374A8A0532239A09 at 92.118.47.206:43471)
    Mar 04 22:30:55.000 [warn] 35 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:30:55.000 [warn]  19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:55.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:30:55.000 [warn]  7 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:32:51.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 36; recommendation warn; host DD0C8EEC5CA402A9FA4478F10C31A440F71F6885 at 195.201.9.37:143)
    Mar 04 22:32:51.000 [warn] 36 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:32:51.000 [warn]  19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:32:51.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:32:51.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:33:16.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 37; recommendation warn; host 835D88AE990CA3A33A49F800F64ACE580F4C21FE at 144.217.92.215:443)
    Mar 04 22:33:16.000 [warn] 37 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:33:16.000 [warn]  20 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:33:16.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:33:16.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
    Mar 04 22:33:40.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 38; recommendation warn; host F6912470A4F8546EF3F0F8ED89A2B566D6267842 at 82.64.159.139:8080)
    Mar 04 22:33:40.000 [warn] 38 connections have failed:
    Mar 04 22:33:40.000 [warn]  21 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:33:40.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write finished in HANDSHAKE
    Mar 04 22:33:40.000 [warn]  8 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
```

I do the process exact same as torproject.org.Even i open the <1024 port and add the nonewprivilage=no to the file but it does not work and still give that error. I search everywhere and do everything but it does not work.

Comment: "This post is hidden. It was deleted 7 days ago by Cody Gray♦.
Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow or post a new one on Super User.

Closed 7 days ago by Shawn, tink, Cody Gray♦."

Have you reposted the same question again?

Comment: @spikey_richie well not exact same but question is the same

Comment: @spikey_richie ops, i think that i repeated the error section